# .htaccess and SocketException: Connection reset, SocketException: Broken pipe

Tags: java, .htaccess

Is there a connection between filrering in .htaccess and SocketException?
Suppose that in .htaccess were made deny for host.are.everywhere.in.the.net
What if I from that denied host... will I recieve SocketException: Connection reset, SocketException: Broken pipe while creating socket and sending some info to it? Or that erros are not connected with limitations in .htaccess?

Or what do these errors says in common case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restrictions in .htaccess usually only affect the data sent by the server, i.e. the server might send a arror code 403 and a HTML page with some error message.

This, however, is all part of the HTTP protocol, and it requires a functioning TCP connection.
The server might close the connection after the response, even if the client want a persistent connection. But this is something the client has to be able to deal with anyway.

In short: no restrictions in .htaccess should not cause the problems you describe.